# Chart Control add x points

Tags: c#, charts

[image: 2j0Q8.png]

I have a chart control. It has 8 points(spots) in x axis, I need 30.

I went through all properties but can't find where to set that. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the AxisX properties of the chart:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 30;
```